# firebase get url by nested child id for tree like

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have following structure in firebase:

```
 data/users/<id_user>/lists/<id_list>/children/<child1_id>/children/<child2_id>
```

how to get this full URL, knowing the only child2_id?

(preferably typescript, angularfire 2)

Comment: You can' t. The realtimedb expects you to know the full path.

Comment: i ended up by storing parent nodes ids in children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database queries can search the child nodes of a location. But the value you search for must be at a fixed path under each child.

So if you know `data/users/<id_user>/lists/<id_list>/children/<child1_id>`, you can query to find the child under that with `child2_id`. But you can't search for `child2_id` across multiple nested unknown paths.

For more on this, see [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested), and possibly (depending on your use-case) [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value).