# Android & Firebase : How can i get data from frebase by key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsLG3.png)

Please how i can get data from firebase with IMEI of the phone.

[image]

How i can get listcarte by the phone TPEID!!

Comment: So the TPEID is the IMEI or?

Comment: HI Alex! yes it is.

Comment: And you want to everything that exist under `cartnoir - > 0`, right?

Comment: For example for the first phone with the IMEI = "869688030960688" it will show [carte1,carte2,carte3,carte4] and for the seconde phone with IMEI="357330078723954" it will show  [carte1,carte3]

Comment: I understand now. One more thing before writing an answer. `Tpe`  and `Tpe`1` are direct children of the root? Or add a more detailed screenshot.

Comment: I just edited the post! thank you

Comment: Hi Alex Im waiting for your help please!

Comment: Hi Yassine! The answer that Frank van Puffelen already provided, it's the same as the one I would have given but he was faster ;) You can use as it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the value you're looking for is always in `0/TPEID`, then you can use a query to find the nodes that contains that value with:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(...);
Query query = ref.orderByChild("0/TPEID").equalTo("869688030960688");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot tpeSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(tpeSnapshot.getKey()); // Tpe0
        System.out.println(tpeSnapshot.child("0/TPEID").getValue(String.class)); // 869688030960688
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
}
```

If the value is not at a fixed path under each child, you won't be able to search for it with a Firebase query. In that case, see [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested/27208492?noredirect=1#comment102509343_27208492), [firebase get url by nested child id for tree like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236178/firebase-get-url-by-nested-child-id-for-tree-like), [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)